# What is the optimal way to loop between two dates in Perl?

Tags: perl, date, loops, iteration

What is the optimal/clearest way to loop between two dates in Perl? There are plenty of modules on CPAN that deal with such matter, but is there any rule of thumb for iterating between two dates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate through range of Dates ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493880/how-to-iterate-through-range-of-dates)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For everything that uses Date manipulation `DateTime` is probably the best module out there. To get all dates between two dates with your own increment use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $start = DateTime->new(
    day   => 1,
    month => 1,
    year  => 2000,
);

my $stop = DateTime->new(
    day   => 10,
    month => 1,
    year  => 2000,
);


while ( $start->add(days => 1) < $stop ) {
    printf "Date: %s\n", $start->ymd('-');
}
```

This will output:

```
Date: 2000-01-02
Date: 2000-01-03
Date: 2000-01-04
Date: 2000-01-05
Date: 2000-01-06
Date: 2000-01-07
Date: 2000-01-08
Date: 2000-01-09
```

Comment: that's a little confusing, in that it starts the day after `$start`

Comment: Best part of this solution: If I need to loop through hours, minutes, seconds, months, or years, I now know exactly what to do.

Answer (score 7):

These days, most people would recommend using [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
use DateTime;   

my $start = DateTime->new(...); # create two DateTime objects
my $end   = DateTime->new(...);

while ($start <= $end) {
    print $start->ymd, "\n";
    $start->add(days => 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm offering up a `Time::Piece` solution, because - unlike `DateTime` it's a core module (as of perl 5.9.5):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d';

my $start = '2016-01-22';
my $end   = '2016-03-11';


my $start_t = Time::Piece->strptime( $start, $FORMAT );
my $end_t   = Time::Piece->strptime( $end,   $FORMAT );

while ( $start_t <= $end_t ) {
   print $start_t ->strftime($FORMAT), "\n";
   $start_t += ONE_DAY;
}
```

Both `Time::Piece` and `Time::Seconds` are core as of perl 5.9.5. The latter is only needed for `ONE_DAY` - otherwise you can just add `60 * 60 * 24` instead.

This has the advantage of being able to parse fairly arbitrary date formats.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "best" way to do that depends a lot on *what* you're doing between these two days.

In many cases, a simple `for (0..31)` loop will suffice.

In other cases, you may wish to use an epoch value, and add/subtract 86400 seconds on each itteration.

In one application I've written, I do exactly this, using a [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.70/lib/DateTime.pm) object that I add one day to for each iteration.  This is likely overkill for many applications, though.

Comment: The approach with adding seconds to epoch usually fails with DST (daylight-saving time). I did that once in one my application and got weird errors half-year later.

Comment: Hopefully all your date manipulations are in UTC where DST doesn't apply, though. :) Sane programmers do it this way... hehe But even so, I never claimed that this was a solution for _every_ case.

Comment: In your application you probably want to show the local time. If you do the math on UTC and convert to the local time it could be that your code breaks. For example adding 1 hour and 1 minute to the UTC time 27.3.2011 01:00:00 and converting it to "Europe/Berlin" will result in an error, because the date is invalid. If you set time_zone before doing the math your code works correctly and returns the same date with the time 03:01:00.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, another option would be to use [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment) that have very good performances (see [the benchmarks](http://blogs.perl.org/users/chansen/2014/08/timemoment-vs-datetime.html)) through a clear interface.

A reimplementation of Sobrique's answer would be:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Moment;

# Same than 'Y-%m-%d'
my $FORMAT = '%F';

my $start = '2020-01-22';
my $end   = '2020-03-11';

my $start_t = Time::Moment->from_string( $start . 'T00Z' );
my $end_t   = Time::Moment->from_string( $end . 'T00Z' );

while ( $start_t <= $end_t ) {
   print $start_t ->strftime( $FORMAT ), "\n";
   $start_t->plus_days( 1 );
}
```

`Time::Moment` isn't a core module, but if you need some extra speed, it can help a bit compared to `Time::Piece` and `DateTime`. Plus, the interface is really easy to read. The date parsing capabilities are maybe a bit less restrictive.