# script for download public data

Tags: perl

I am using the perl script below to download the "Diário Oficial da União" (a Brazilian public document that gathers and publishes daily the formal acts of the federal government). It works fine, but I'm trying to add the following features:

1. download a period of time, for example, from 01/01/2010 to 12/31/2010
2. direct the files to a specific folder

I can not download per period (for example 01/01/2016 to 12/31/2016). I can only download the files today or a specific day. Any suggestion?

```
$|=1;
use DateTime;
# my $dt=DateTime->now; 
my $dt=DateTime->new(
   year       => 1995,
   month      => 01,
   day        => 02,
);
$ymd=$dt->ymd; 
$dmy=$dt->dmy("/"); 

print "Data: $dmy\n";

use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::Simple::Cookies ( autosave => 1,
    file => "lwp_cookies.dat" ); 

my $jornal;
my @jornais=('1','2','3','515','529','530','531','521','525', '2000');
foreach $jornal (@jornais) {
    print "Jornal: $jornal\n";
    $doc = get("http://pesquisa.in.gov.br/imprensa/jsp/visualiza/index.jsp?jornal=$jornal&pagina=1&data=$dmy");
    if ( $doc=~/&totalArquivos=(\d*)"/ ){
        $paginas=$1;
        print "Paginas: $paginas\n";
        foreach $i ( 1..$paginas) { 
            my $arq="IN-Jornal $jornal - $ymd - pag_$i.pdf";
            print "$arq (existe)\n" if -e $arq; 
            getstore("http://pesquisa.in.gov.br/imprensa/servlet/INPDFViewer?jornal=$jornal&pagina=$i&data=$dmy&captchafield=firstAccess",$arq ) && print "$arq (ok)\n" if !-e $arq;
            if ( $i == 1) {
                    use CAM::PDF; 
                    $bigpdf = CAM::PDF->new("$arq");
            } else {
                    my $anotherpdf = CAM::PDF->new("$arq");   
                    $bigpdf->appendPDF($anotherpdf);  
            }
            sleep 1;
        }
        $bigpdf->cleanoutput("IN-Jornal $jornal - $ymd.pdf"); 
     } else { print "IN-Jornal $jornal não disponível!\n" }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I'm guessing you need help to do (1) and (2). If so, then tell us what you have tried and what difficulties you are having.

Comment: @Dada I can not download per period (for example 01/01/2016 to 12/31/2016). I can only download the files today or a specific day. Any suggestion?

Comment: well, you could create range of days, you want to download..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6622999/1331451 tells you how to create a range of days.